# Add post to WordPress site remotely

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have multiple clients which have WordPress installed on their servers. I also have their username and passwords.

1. I need to make a system as such when I add a post on my server it should post to all the clients server automatically and add it to their respective database.
2. Also when I update or delete it should perform the action on clients server automatically.

I am new to WordPress so no idea how do I go ahead and perform this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that

1. You can either create main network and add multiple wordpress sites to join your network if there are hosted on single server. Check the codex for more details

   https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
2. There are plugins available to manage multiple wordpress sites through single login, not just that you can even manage their plugins, themes & settings. Check out the plugins page

   http://mainwp.com/

   https://www.wpkube.com/go/managewp

   https://infinitewp.com/

   https://www.icontrolwp.com/

   https://wpremote.com/
3. You can even manage all wordpress sites via desktop application developed by wordpress.com, install and add wordpress logins.

   https://apps.wordpress.com/desktop/

Comment: The other websites are on different servers. I just have their username ans password of wp-admin and their website link. is there a way that I can write a script that will post automatically?

Comment: If you need custom script to do so then i don't think so there's any script written as there are plugins available but you can try googling it...

Comment: I tried http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/xml-rpc-in-wordpress--wp-25467 but not working.

Comment: Can you tell me any plugin name which dose it ?

Comment: mainwp. Also check desktop application, it has that option too

Comment: desktop application wont be useful for me as ill be pushing the articles from my server.